# Maps fragment not getting inflated in Micromax Android one phone

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

The setContentView is not working in Micromax Android phone:
I am just running the default code that the studio provides when
MapsActivity Layout is selected(changing the android key) 
But which running i am getting this error:

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.naveen.mapstrial/com.naveen.mapstrial.MapsActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
(ZygoteInit.java:903)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView
(PhoneWindow.java:378)
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2145)
at com.naveen.mapstrial.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:20)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.io.File.mkdir()' on a null object reference
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.m.ad.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.c.h.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.c.y.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.bd.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.ev.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.z.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.y.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.u.onTransact(SourceFile:107)
at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:380)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$zza$zza.
onCreateView(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zza.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza$4.zzb(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState
(FragmentManager.java:1036)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState
(FragmentManager.java:1226)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment
(FragmentManager.java:1328)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView
(FragmentManager.java:2284)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView
(FragmentController.java:111)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.
dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:314)
at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.
onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:31)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView
(FragmentActivity.java:79)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:733)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView
(PhoneWindow.java:378) 
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2145) 
at com.naveen.mapstrial.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:20) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate
(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: Post your code please

Comment: merely error log wont help. is it running on all other devices

Comment: I just ran the default code that android studio provides when we choose "Google maps activity" in new activity chooser(changed the android key). when i run that code in other phones it is working properly but in micromax android one phone it it giving this error.

Comment: I have same problem on android emulator